# ASP.Net core web app failure on AWS Cognito intergration

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito

I have a simple ASP.NET web app with 2 pages, the app builds and runs on localhost, I wanted to protect the app via authentication with AWS Cognito.

I followed all Cognito - ASP.NET intergration steps from : https://dotnet-developer-dojo.workshop.aws/lab5-cognito.html but i get the error : InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.